# Reading CSV Files from S3 Bucket is taking a long time using Boto3 Python

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to read the read csv file from S3 Bucket using Boto3 and Pandas Python Module. The size of the csv file is 130 MB and it has 35000 rows. Its taking 23 secs to read a file.. What i am doing wrong here. Is there a efficient way to reduce the time taken.

import boto3
import pandas as pd

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='Bucket_name')
    all = response["Contents"]
    latest = max(all, key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
    latest_file = (latest['Key'])
    print(latest_file)

df = pd.read_csv('https://web-data.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/' + latest_file)

df = df.query('`Searched Job Location` == @job_loc & `Searched Job Title` == @job_title')
```

Comment: I think it would be a little simpler had you just downloaded that csv file to a temporary location locally and processed it there.   After process, you can remove it.

Comment: try downloading the file outside Python and passing it in to your script

Comment: @ewong  Thank you so much for the response. I forget to mention that my app is running on Heroku and its a Django framework .In that case where to save the downloaded  csv..

Comment: Terribly inconvenient to have to download a CSV from S3 to local just to read it into memory.